# android unable to see device folders on eclipse file explorer

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I update my eclipse and I am testing on a real android device. I can see device on DDMS and when selected, on file explorer, data folder is empty! I create a new AVD and restart eclipse but problem persists. Before update I could see properly all app folders. Thank you

Comment: which version of eclipse you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have a developer or rooted phone so you don't have read right on those folders. You should try with an emulator who has all the rights on the `data` folder.